# roxygen2 ignores a single file in the R folder

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm working on a package ([this one](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgisLT/tree/dev/R)) and trying to generate documentation (.Rd files) for the functions. For some reason one file in the R folder is completely ignored by roxygen2 and I cannot figure out why...The file in question is [utils_shiny.R](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgisLT/blob/858b9dc1bf00faf07ceb91088f236a4967c21db6/R/utils_shiny.R). There is a very similar file, [utils.R](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgisLT/blob/858b9dc1bf00faf07ceb91088f236a4967c21db6/R/utils.R), for which the .Rd files are generated as expected. Both files contain unexported functions and have the same/similar set of roxygen tags. If I put all the functions from `utils_shiny` into `utils` then the .Rd files are generated...

I tried erasing all .Rd files as suggestest by [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866898/roxygen2-not-generating-rd-file#31867023), delete the NAMESPACE, rename `utils_shiny.R` but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm using `roxygen 6.0.1, devtools 1.13.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I forgot about some entries in `.Rbuildignore` that were causing the build to ignore more files that were originally intended, among others the mentioned file (utils_shiny.R).